# Python Dictionary Manipulation in rpg

Tags: python

I am making a basic python RPG for my daughter and looking for the best way to store character stats that can be added a and subtracted from. Right now, I am using a dictionary so that she can view a list of her stats; however, I can't see a way to automatically add or subtract from objects in the list.

For example, I have

```
CatAbilities = {'speed': 5, 'claw': 3}
```

etc. And I want to have speed go down by 2 when, for example, her cat runs to avoid a dog. Is there a better way to do this while keeping a structure that let's her view her stats easily?

Comment: `CatAbilities['speed'] += 1` ?

Comment: what about `CatAbilities['speed'] -= 2`

Comment: Thanks! All that googling and I didn't realize it was that easy. Learning...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use classes?

```
class Animal:
  def __init__(self):
    self.Abilities = {}
  def PrintStats(self):
    print self.Abilities

class Cat(Animal):
  def __init__(self):
    self.Abilities = {'speed': 5, 'claw': 3}

  def ChasedByDog(self):
    self.Abilities['speed'] -= 2

def main():
  Kitty = Cat()
  Kitty.PrintStats()
  Kitty.ChasedByDog()
  Kitty.PrintStats()


if(__name__ == '__main__'):
  main()
```

Comment: Just because I'm not good enough yet! I'm trying to learn basics this way and only just now trying lists and dictionaries but I will keep that code for the next game!